# speed up a Pandas fillna by subcatagory mean (how to replace a for loop)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, fillna

My data contains several sub categories coded in the column "RID", I'm filling by the mean of each sub category. The code I've been using is very slow. Looking for a better method that gets rid of the for loop.

```
filled = mergedf.copy()
for c,v in enumerate(mergedf.RID.unique()):
    filled.loc[filled.RID == v, :] = filled.loc[filled.RID == v, :].fillna(filled.loc[filled.RID == v, :].mean())

filled.info()
```

I've been trying the following to speed it up as someone suggested groupby, but I can't get the merges to work properly.

```
pts_mean = mergedf.groupby("RID").mean()
fill2 = merge.combine_first(pts_mean)

fill3 = pd.merge(mergedf, pts_mean, on="RID", how="left")
```

I've experimented with how = "inner" as well as how = "outer"

looking at my test data, before:

```
print(mergedf.loc[mergedf.RID==2,"FDG"])
0     1.36926
1     1.21655
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11        NaN
12        NaN
```

after the slow method (this is the desired result, I just don't want it to take so long)

```
print(filled.loc[filled.RID==2,"FDG"])
0     1.369260
1     1.216550
2     1.292905
3     1.292905
4     1.292905
5     1.292905
6     1.292905
7     1.292905
8     1.292905
9     1.292905
10    1.292905
11    1.292905
12    1.292905
```

after the combine_first method

```
print(fill2.loc[fill2.RID==2,"FDG"])
0     1.369260
1     1.216550
2     1.292905
3     1.074235
4          NaN
5     1.319690
6          NaN
7          NaN
8     1.264300
9          NaN
10    1.042469
11         NaN
12         NaN
```

after the pd.merge

```
print(fill3.loc[fill3.RID==2,["FDG_x","FDG_y"]])
      FDG_x     FDG_y
0   1.36926  1.292905
1   1.21655  1.292905
2       NaN  1.292905
3       NaN  1.292905
4       NaN  1.292905
5       NaN  1.292905
6       NaN  1.292905
7       NaN  1.292905
8       NaN  1.292905
9       NaN  1.292905
10      NaN  1.292905
11      NaN  1.292905
12      NaN  1.292905
```

Comment: Try: `filled['FDG'].fillna(filled['FDG'].groupby('RID')['FDG'].transform('mean'))`

Comment: Took a couple of edits and I got to this:
```
fill4 = filled.fillna(filled.groupby('RID').transform('mean'))```
The filled['FDG'].groupby('RID') caused an error as that slice doesn't contain the categorical column RID, I dropped that and it worked fine for the FDG column. Dropping the remaining slices and it generalised to the whole dataframe, thank you! Much faster!

Comment: Just timed them both, 13.8s for @ScottBoston, 97.2s for my original version. Thanks Scott. (How do I mark this as answered?)

Comment: see solution below click the check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try the following, using `groupby` with `transform`:

```
filled['FDG'].fillna(filled.groupby('RID')['FDG'].transform('mean'))
```

or

```
fill4 = filled.fillna(filled.groupby('RID').transform('mean'))
```

Comment: I think the line in the specific column case (first one) should be:

filled['FDG'].fillna(filled.groupby('RID')['FDG'].transform('mean'))

otherwise this line fails as the column to groupby is not in the slice/dataframe.

Comment: @tnankie I believe you are correct.  This is why most times poster provide sample data to eliminate syntax and typo errors like this.   Thank you!